How should template result values be correctly nested in other template structs?
I am trying to conditionally choose a type Res based on a template type T.
The condition is if T has a specific member type (declared with using), then set Res to that member type. Otherwise, set Res to another type.
This can be (successfully) done with the std::conditional type trait.
I encounter issues though when I want to use Res in a different template class as a member type (also declared with using).
#include <experimental/type_traits>

template<typename T>
class DifferenceData;

template<class T>
using hasDifferenceType = typename T::DifferenceType;

template<typename T>
struct MyDifferenceType {
    using DifferenceType = typename std::conditional<std::experimental::is_detected<hasDifferenceType, T>::value,
            typename T::DifferenceType, DifferenceData<T>>::type;
};

class IntegerDifferenceData;

class Integer {
public:
    using DifferenceType = IntegerDifferenceData;
};

class String {
};

template<typename T>
class DifferenceData {
public:
};

class IntegerDifferenceData : public DifferenceData<Integer> {
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::experimental::is_detected<hasDifferenceType, Integer>::value);
    static_assert(!std::experimental::is_detected<hasDifferenceType, String>::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<typename MyDifferenceType<Integer>::DifferenceType, IntegerDifferenceData>::value);
    // The line below produces an error: "no type named 'DifferenceType' in 'class String'"
    // static_assert(std::is_same<typename MyDifferenceType<String>::DifferenceType, DifferenceData<String>>::value);

    return 0;
}

In the code example, the Integer class has DifferenceType defined and String does not.
MyDifferenceType implements the condition described above: use the defined DifferenceType if the template argument has this member type defined, otherwise use the default DifferenceData<T> type.
The error that I get when uncommenting the final static_assert is "no type named 'DifferenceType' in 'class String'".
I do not understand why this happens because the previous static_assert that checks that String does not define DifferenceType is successful...
What am I missing and how can I fix the issue?
Thanks in advance!

Generic way of lazily evaluating (short-circuiting) with std::conditional_t and this answer in second dupe Is it possible to build a lazy conditional metafunction that uses std::experimental::detected_or_t

Both types of std::conditional should exist, you might delay resolution with extra indirection
// helper to have name "type" as for std::type_identity
template<class T>
struct DifferenceTypeT
{
    using type = typename T::DifferenceType;
};

template <typename T>
struct MyDifferenceType {
    using DifferenceType =
        typename std::conditional_t<
            std::experimental::is_detected<hasDifferenceType, T>::value,
            DifferenceTypeT<T>,
            std::type_identity<DifferenceData<T>>>::type;
};

std::type_identity is C++20, but reimplementable for previous standard.
